# Python inheritance, method overloading, and decorating

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a class B that inherits from A :

```
class A():
    def do_something(self, x):
        """Prints x."""
        print(x)

class B(A):
    def something_else(self, x):
        print("This isn't the same.")
```

I'd like to achieve a few things :

- I'd like for `B.do_something` to inherit the docstring from `A.do_something`. I think `functools.wraps` is the recommended solution : is that right ?
- Let's say there are some methods of `A` that return an instance of `A`. If I call those methods from `B`, I'd like them to return an instance of `B`. So far, I'm overloading each function manually.

  ```
  def method_of_A(self, *args, **kwargs):
      return A(super(self.__class__, self).method_of_A(*args, **kwargs))
  ```

  There's likely a better way - especially given that I have to do this for a large number of classes. Is there same way to check if a function is defined within `B` and, if not but available in `A`, have it decorated / wrapped to return an instance of `B` ? EDIT : I can't make changes to `A`'s codebase.
- Are there solutions that are Py2 and Py3 compatible ?

Thanks very much for any suggestions.

Comment: How about doing something like "new_instance = type(self)(...)"

Comment: but if you copy the docstring of `"prints x"` to a function that does something that `"isn't the same."` isn't that a bad idea?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen : if it's a simple function overload that returns a type B instead of a type A, given that B inherits from A, no, it's not a bad idea ! This is the only case where I'd want to inherit the doc strings.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `functools.wraps` to copy the function name and docstring.  You can return an instance of the current class using `self.__class__`

```
class A(object):

    def func(self):
        return self.__class__()

class B(A):

    @functools.wraps(A.func)
    def func(self):
        return super(B, self).func()
```

```
>>> b = B()
>>> obj = b.return_object()
>>> print type(obj)
"<class '__main__.B'>"
```

> Is there same way to check if a function is defined within B and, if not but available in A, have it decorated / wrapped to return an instance of B?

You may be able to do this using `metaclasses`, assuming `A` isn't already using a custom metaclass that you're not able to inherit from (like if it is only defined in C and hasn't been exposed to python).  The way you use metaclasses is slightly different in python 2 and 3.

```
class MetaB(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if A in bases:
            for attr, value in A.__dict__.items():
                if isinstance(value, types.FunctionType) and attr not in attrs:
                    new_func = MyMeta.make_wrapper_func(value)
                    attrs[attr] = new_func

        return super(MetaB, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

    @staticmethod
    def make_wrapper_func(func):

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def _func(self, *args, **kwargs):
            value = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            if isinstance(value, A):
                value = self.__class__(value)
            return value

        return _func



class B(A):
    __metaclass__ = MetaB

    ...
```

In python 3, metaclasses are used a little differently

```
class B(A, metaclass=MetaB):
    ...
```

This assumes you can create an object of the `B()` type just by passing an instance of `A()` to the constructor for it (ie. `return self.__class__(value)`).  That was just a guess.  I'd have to know a litte more about your object to know how to translate an `A` object to a `B` object, but the general method would be the same.  This solution also only works on regular class methods.  It's not going to work on some other stuff like `classmethods` and `staticmethods` or other types of descriptor objects.  You certainly could make it work for all those, your metaclass would just need to be a little more complex.

Comment: Thanks - I should have been clearer in that I'm not writing `A`, I'm extending someone else's code ! I've edited my question.

Comment: I think this is both overkill and wrong in some ways. To start with - you are aware that `isinstance` will always return True to subclasses of  a given class, aren' t you?

Comment: @jsbueno The user wants to dynamically create functions with a single purpose (casting return types) based off class inheritance and functions that may not exist until runtime.  Metaclasses are good for this.  The only other option would be a class decorator, which wouldn't be any less complex and would have several disadvantages compared to metaclasses.  Yes, I am aware about isinstance, which use of it do you find questionable?

Comment: no, it is fine I thogut you were using `isinstance(value, A) `    to test for instances of `B` or `A` in which case it would always return true - but it is just to guard against return values that do not return `A`instances.

I also had no attempeted to the fact the OP can't change the code of `A` itself - therefore this approach is just fine.

Comment: @jsbueno.  Yeah, I suppose isinstance could be dangerous in those cases if the return value was some *other* subclass of `A` that the user didn't want to wrap.  Since the user didn't have control of `A`, I just assumed it would be unlikely for `A` to be returning `B` objects.

Comment: then, you can just use `type(value) == A` instead of `isinstance`

Comment: Also, unless `A` is defined in native code, you can simply swap the `__class__` attribute of `value` instead of creating a new class assuming it can take `A` as a parameter to `__init__`: `if type(value) == A: value.__class__ = B `

Answer (score -1):

> Let's say there are some methods of A that return an instance of A. If I call those methods from B, I'd like them to return an instance of B. So far, I'm overloading each function manually.

Use a classmethod.

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def f(cls):
        return cls
```

when b (instance of B) will call f, it will return B.